# How could I compress/optimize this code (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I'm looking to optimize this code and hopefully take less space. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery, so I'm not quite sure how it would be done.

```
rankedSolo5["Wins"] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5].wins;
$("#rankedWinsSolo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5["Wins"]);

rankedSolo5["Assists"] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5].aggregatedStats.totalAssists;
$("#rankedAssistsSolo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5["Assists"]);

rankedSolo5["Kills"] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5].aggregatedStats.totalChampionKills;
$("#rankedKillsSolo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5["Kills"]);

rankedSolo5["MinKills"] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5].aggregatedStats.totalMinionKills;
$("#rankedMinKillsSolo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5["MinKills"]);

rankedSolo5["NeutralMinKills"] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5].aggregatedStats.totalNeutralMinionsKilled;
$("#rankedNeutralMinKillsSolo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5["NeutralMinKills"]);

rankedSolo5["TurretsKilled"] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5].aggregatedStats.totalTurretsKilled;
$("#rankedTurretsKilledSolo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5["TurretsKilled"]);
```

Comment: less space as in what? Your question leans towards JS minification although you tagged this is the 'DRY' tag - can you be more specific?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I added the DRY tag, I thought that's what he's looking for.

Comment: It would help if the properties of `aggregatedStats` were the same as the properties of `rankedSolo5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an object that relates the property names in `rankedSolo5` to those in `aggregatedStats`:

```
var fields = {
    "Wins": "wins",
    "Assists": "totalAssists",
    "Kills": "totalChampionKills",
    ...
};
```

Then you can loop over this to perform the same operations:

```
$.each(fields, function(rankedProp, statsProp) {
    rankedSolo5[rankedProp] = jsonData.playerStatSummaries[5][statsProp];
    $("#ranked" + rankedProp + "Solo5 .statsValue").html(rankedSolo5[rankedProp]);
});
```